# How prove that $Y$ is a smooth vector field on $S^2$

Tags: smooth-manifolds, vector-bundles, vector-fields, spheres

I have to solve this one:

> "Does $Y(x,y,z)=(xz,yz,z^2-1)$ is a smooth vector field on $S^2$?"

First of all $Y$ is smooth since I can compute all the partial derivatives. For any $p\in S^2$ we have that $T_p S^2=\{v\in\mathbb{R}^3$ such that $p\cdot v=0\}$. If we make the identification $Y=xz\frac{\partial}{\partial x}+yz\frac{\partial}{\partial y}+(z^2-1)\frac{\partial}{\partial z}\leftrightarrow (xz,yz,z^2-1)\in\mathbb{R}^3$ we have that for every $p=(x,y,z)\in S^2$

\begin{equation}
(x,y,z)\cdot(xz,yz,z^2-1)=x^2z+y^2z+z(z^2-1)=z(x^2+y^2+z^2-1)=0.
\end{equation}

So for every $p\in S^2$, $Y(p)\in T_pS^2$ and so $Y$ is a vector field on $S^2$.

Is that all right?

Any other idea?

Thanks

Comment: That $Y$ is smooth is all the question asks for. There is no requirement - at least that you reproduced - that $Y$ be tangent. There are other vector bundles over $S^2$ than $TS^2$.